# Centering Fixed Width Page Content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resize, window-resize

I'm pretty lost as to where to even begin so I will try to explain. I'm making a Hardware Store for my term project in Aptana Studio and am running the site in Google Chrome. Apparently, running a site in Google Chrome makes it automatically responsive? As you can see in the following screenshots, the site is fixed on the left side and responsive on the right side:

(resize 1)

[image]

(resize 2)

[image]

(resize 3)

[image]

(resize 4)

[image]

Of course, the black and white photo does not resize, but I actually don't want it to. I just want what is in the header (the logo and photograph) to stay the same size - to stay fixed on the page. Take Ace Harware's website as an example: http://www.acehardware.com/home/index.jsp

Everything in the site is constrained to certain dimensions. When the page is fully open, the content is centered and there is a margin of white space on either side. And when the page is resized (smaller), the margins start to disappear until finally there is a cutoff point - and the content does not change position anymore.

(full page)

[image]

(first resize)

[image]

(second resize - even though the page is smaller, the content is fixed)

[image]

This is exactly what I'm trying to do with my Hardware Store site. How do I achieve this effect? I've heard of bootstrap but I really don't know enough about it or which template I would use. Thanks for any help/adivce. If it's too complicated to explain here, please send me to a good tutorial you might know of.

Comment: You should be making everything responsive with the prevalence of mobile devices. Using a framework like bootstrap to do your scaffolding and the basics for your layout will make everything work semi well across all device sizes and save you time. Bootstrap is fairly straight forward, so I would start by looking at the documentation and going from there. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do (at least, what i understood) is not a matter of "responsive". You're just trying to keep the whole page content always centered. (acehardware.com is not responsive eather).

You just need to define a constant width for the main div (the one which will contain the whole page content, except the background), and then keep it centered in the outer div, no matter the screen size.

This is what you got to do:

```css
#main-wraper {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 420px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#outter-div {
    background-color: grey;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='outter-div'>
    <div id='main-wraper'>
        <!-- The whole page content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This will keep the div centered in the parent container, and the parent container will be hidden the smaller the screen is.

I used smaller dimensions for main-wrapper in the snippet in order to make it easier for you to watch the effect in a smaller box. BUt you should use your own width. Just have in mind that the "left margin" for that div must have "half the width of the div" as a negative value. "left: 50%" will always center the div and keep the effect.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm trying to do! Unfortunately, everything disappeared when I tried it.... 

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/tbx8kunL/1/

Any idea what went wrong?